# how to get name of iphoto album

Tags: applescript, iphoto

I'm trying to get at the name of the album with applescript/iphoto. So far I've got this

```
tell application "iPhoto"
activate
set theEvents to get every album
repeat with aEvent in theEvents
    log name of aEvent
end repeat
end tell
```

but when it prints the names I get this :

```
(*name of album id 6.442450942E+9*)
(*name of album id 6.442450941E+9*)
(*name of album id 6.44245094E+9*)
```

not quite what i wanted. I'm quite new to applescript so I suspect something basic is going wrong, but the few examples I've seen on line seem to do something like this. any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

may have found answer. I've seen hints that it's not possible to directly access the Event Name with applescript unlike an albums name (seems silly to me, but that's what I've found at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "iPhoto"
activate
set theEvents to get every album
repeat with aEvent in theEvents
    log (get name of aEvent)
end repeat
end tell
```

The `log` command does not implicitly dereference the object specifier you are passing.  Adding a `get` command does this.

Comment: son of a gun. after reading some other sites I was thinking this wasn't possible. thanks so much.

Comment: This returns the name of the album, not the name of the event though. It seems like iPhoto 9.6 does not expose events in applescript.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer #1, has already been accepted but I wanted to post this for future readers.

```
    tell application "iPhoto" to set theEvents to get name of every album


    #You can then use the theEvents list.


    #Example - log  items of theEvents 
    log theEvents
--> {"Events", "Faces", "Places", "Photos", "Last 12 Months", "Last Import", "Flagged","Trash", "My Photo Stream", "Holiday 2008", "Holiday Sep 2008"}



    #Example -  work though the items of theEvents with a repeat loop

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theEvents
        set this_item to item i of theEvents
        if this_item contains "Holiday" then
            log this_item
-->(*Holiday 2008*)
-->(*Holiday Sep 2008*)
        end if
    end repeat
```

Comment: thanks. this is where I was really going. I want to loop through all of the events and just the events. would you be able to post the snippet that does just that?

Comment: I had a look at that. You can do set theEventAlbum to events album. And the should be able to do.
 set theEventAlbumChildren to children of theEventAlbum. But It does not return any of the events !!